# What is the name of the clause stating that the expected result did not follow the cause stated in the main clause?

Tags: grammar, terminology, coordinating-conjunctions, subordinate-clauses

What is the name of the clause stating that the expected result did not follow the cause stated in the main clause?

1. "He did not succeed **although he worked hard**."

   **concessive clause**

   (1st clause = absence of expected result; 2nd clause = presence of potential cause)
2. "He worked hard **but he did not succeed**."

   **What is this clause called?**

   (1st clause = presence of potential cause; 2nd clause = absence of expected result)

Comment: Simply _contrastive_ (note that it's a main clause): [Google:] **but**
conjunction
1.
used to introduce something contrasting with what has already been mentioned.

Comment: ["Very interesting ... but stupid!"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkFx3TaOunA). Alternatively, [stupid, but interesting](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JzqumbhfxRo&list=PL0F3D784BB8C154A4&index=10). How are we to use this term (assuming one exists) in contexts where it's not clear which is the cause, and which is the "unexpected result" (including failure of the "expected result" to arise/apply)?

Comment: "Although" introduces a *concessive* clause. "But" introduces an *adversative* clause. You can also say that "but" introduces the *antithesis.*

Comment: @Cerberus: If that's the standard terminology (I don't know, obviously - but it sounds good to me, and I assume *you* know), you should probably post it as an answer. Personally, I don't think it's good for ELU to have too many unanswered questions. If there *is* an answer it should be identifiable as such. And those questions where there *isn't* an answer (for whatever reason) should probably be closed after a reasonable period.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: There are probably more than a few terms. Different people, different words. But these are at least acceptable, and what I was taught. I did not feel like pretending to give a definitive answer, though.

Comment: @Cerberus: Fair enough. I can't see why I'd ever want to go beyond Edwin's *contrastive*, though. The next subdivision I'm more likely to care about is *which (if any) of the two clauses is more "important" in the entire context*. Your *concessive/adversative* and *antithesis* seem more "generic" to me than OP's *cause/effect*. But there's always the possibility that any such low-level "naming of the parts" will end up naming the most common cases, at the expense of confusing the issue for less common cases which should still by rights be included.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Cause and effect are not directly related to the kinds of clauses introduced by *although* and *but*: they exist on a higher level. I'm also not sure cause and effect are really central to the OP's question: I think he was mainly looking for a general word like *antithesis* or *opposition*. He did name specific conjunctions in different subheadings, so I gave the labels that they commonly get...but, sure different answers are possible.

Comment: If there is no standard terminology for the specific case, then it deserves to be brought out into the academic community. A name is indeed needed for this structure.

Comment: The problem with 'contrastive' is that even when there is no (inoperative here) cause-effect relationship between the phenomena mentioned in the two clauses, as in 'He worked hard but his sister did not.' you also talk about 'contrast'. 'Contrast' and 'opposition' are often taken to be synonyms. Tacitly, there is a sensu lato where 'contrast/opposition' is used whether a cause-effect relationship exists or not, and a sensu stricto, where 'contrast' and 'opposition' differ: 'contrast' if there is not any cause-effect relationship, 'opposition' if there is. What does OP mean?

Comment: @Cerberus: I have seen 'adversative' used for 'but' clauses as well as 'although' clauses…

Comment: The terminology is fluid, because there is different syntax, but not really a different meaning. _Adversative_ is also used for constructions like _He had his tires slashed_, where the _have_ + `Past Participle` construction refers to something bad that happens to the subject (there's a similar adversative sense of the Japanese "passive" construction).

Comment: I was also wondering why the absence of the expected result only seems to be expressed in coordinate clauses, not in subordinate ones… Why not, as there is precisely no compelling (?) relationship between the events in the two clauses. But then again, the concessive clause is a subordinate clause, not a coordinate…

Answer (score 1):

This, I believe, would be called an *adversative* clause.

Answer (score 0):

"Sentences which are constructed using the linking words and, but, or and the few words which can be used in the same way, like also, too, yet, are called compound sentences. These linking words for compound sentences are known as coordinators since they serve to connect main clauses on an equal footing."

In other words, this clause doesn't have it's own specific name, but is a "main clause", and the one you mentioned, the concessive clause, belongs to "Subordinate clauses".